# Adding new field conditioned by analysis that regards other layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I'm searching for a method to add a new field in the point vector that has a specific value of a field contained in a polygon vector with QGIS. Here is an example image: 
The violet is the point shapefile to which I want to add the number of the polygon (in black) which contains them.

Someone has any idea?

[image]

Comment: Try the SAGA tool: `Add polygon attributes to points` from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it worked! I noticed similar questions were asked: [How to spatially join polygon fields onto a point layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/how-to-spatially-join-polygon-fields-onto-a-point-layer-in-qgis); [Update point shapefile attributes from polygon shapefile using QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125042/update-point-shapefile-attributes-from-polygon-shapefile-using-qgis); [How to get point attribute from polygon layer?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/how-to-get-point-attribute-from-polygon-layer)

Comment: So your question may get flagged as a duplicate :)